# Auto vertical align any auto sized image

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I can't find an answer that is not on a fixed image size so I'm going to ask it.

I have a div with an image in it and that picture could be any size. I need it to auto scale AND auto align. I can scale it fine but vertically aligning it is a bit of a challenge. I need it to be center vertically aligned.

HTML + CSS

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <img src="./img/example.png"></img>
</div>


#myDiv {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 text-align: center;
}

#myDiv img {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 70%;
 max-width: 70%
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting I've tried adding 'line-height' into the parent and setting 'vertical-align: middle;' but if the line height is a percentage it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example forces both horizontal and vertical alignment of an image inside a box; in this specific case, constrained to 130x130px. Change the width and height defined as 130px in 2 separate places each in the css to change the constrained size.

[edit: added simplified example showing minimum required setup]

**Simplified example:**

html:

```
<div class="pic">
  <img src="/path/to/pic.jpg"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.pic {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    outline: solid 1px #cccce3;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.pic:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.pic img {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Complete example:**

Original codepen showing more complex example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/culvD .

Here's the html:

```
<ul class="pics">
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="/path/to/pic1.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="/path/to/pic2.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here's the css:

```
ul.pics {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.pics li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #e6e6ec;
    outline: solid 1px #cccce3;
}

ul.pics li .pic {
    height: 130px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.pics li .pic:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.pics li img {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to reverse engineer what you've done to suit my needs. I'll try though, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I should have simplified the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hepwc . The important parts are to place the img tag inside a parent container. The css now shown in this codepen is the minimum required, aside from the optional outline to show the centering taking effect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "auto sized". Give it a try - this will take any image size and constrain it to a maximum width and height, while preserving aspect ratio. Just do not set a specific width or height on the img tag or in the css - let the max-width and max-height do that for you.

Comment: BOOM! That worked!!! Thank you. Trying to figure out why now. Is it the .pic:before that's doing it? Not used that method before. Thank you

Comment: I've forked your Codepen to show what I mean by auto size. The picture will shrink and stay in the middle on screen resize:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJHyp

Comment: Yeah, the :before pseudo is the magic. Had to google a bit to find out where I learned this technique: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ , example is found when you search the page for "ghost". Same thing, but with font-size: 0 instead of the margin-right hack (see the very last paragraph for the font-size note).

Answer (score -2):

to center align an element to the center asign it a width, then margin-left and right to auto.

Comment: Your answer has been automatically flagged as Low Quality. Please try to add more detail (or a working code sample) to improve it.